# When rendering XML using razor cshtml how do I fix or remove validation in visual studio

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2010, razor

I have a cshtml file which generates xml.
How do I remove the green squiggles which say `Validation (XHTML 1.0 Transitional): Element '....' is not supported.`

[image]

Comment: Surprised no one has an answer for this. Is there any way to link Razor to a simple XSD schema file?

Answer (score 0):

This error shows if you use HTML5 tags, but your visual studio is not setup for HTML5. This error will not affect any of your design and will render nicely in your browser. So actually this not error.

If you really want this error to be removed follow the below steps,

_Layout page must have . indicates we are using HTML5.(this is default in case of MVC 3 and above)
In your visual studio, go to debug menu->tools->options->Expand HTML->select validation.
In the Target dropdown list, select HTML5, click ok. Thats it. Now the error should disappear.